# Turn off clipping in a d3 projection

Tags: d3.js, geo

I have a projection that does not need clipping. Neither anti-meridian or small circle clipping is there a way to not use either

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is this solution. Set the clip angle to 181 degrees.

```
projection(globeProjection.clipAngle(181))
```

Don't know if this is doing a bunch of calculation and if it is possible to do better