# d3.geo.path rectangle wrapping the wrong way

Tags: d3.js, geojson, geo

This simple geojson rectangle is displayed correctly with some geojson viewers, I get a rectangle as expected. But when I do it with d3, the rectangle seems to wrap around.

```js
var polygonData = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [ -100, -20 ],
            [ -100, 20 ],
            [ 100, 20 ],
            [ 100, -20 ],
            [ -100, -20 ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    };
    
    var width = 1000;
    var height = 500;
    
    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
      .scale(100)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
      .rotate([0, 0])
   .center([0, 0])
      .precision(0);
    
    var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr({
        width: width,
       height: height
      });

    svg.append('path')
      .datum(polygonData)
      .attr({
        d: path,
        fill: 'orange',
        opacity: 0.5
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Here is what I get with a [geojson viewer](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:biovisualize/e1138c4419665f0a1d2b&map=2/0.2/0.0):

[image: geojson viewer]

But here's what I get with the above [d3 code](http://blockbuilder.org/biovisualize/583d18e90c37e5bf79d6):

[image: geojson using d3]

Reversing the winding order just fills the opposite shapes, it doesn't fix the problem. I guess its an antimeridian cutting issue. One fix is to add some intermediate points to force the path to not wrap around, but I would need to be able to automate this solution with more complex paths.

Any idea how I can use this geojson with d3 and force it to show it like other geojson viewers, as a simple rectangle across the map?

Comment: Switching from he default antimeridian cutting to small circle clipping seems to do the trick: projection.clipAngle(181) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30996241/537080 I wonder if a better fix would be to use projection streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think, there is anything to blame on D3; in my understanding it's those other GeoJSON viewers which are in error. As a human being living on a more or less planar surface one is easily tricked into believing that a polygon with four corners having carefully chosen coordinates like yours should look like a rectangle. On a sufficiently small scale and given a suitable projection this even holds true for spherical geometry. But as your points are almost half the globe apart, this won't be the case.

To shed some light on this, I used an orthographic projection to display some geographic features along with your polygon:

[image: Orthographic projection]

From this view it becomes apparent that the line along the meridian is the first edge connecting points `[-100,-20]` and `[-100,20]`. From that point `[-100,20]` somewhere in Mexico to the northwest is the [great arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), i.e. the shortest connection, to the next point `[100,20]` half way around the globe. The path is then similarly closed around the southern hemisphere. Thus, the outline of the polygon is the shortest path on the globe's surface connecting all of its points in the given order.

Although your polygon is determined by its coordinates, its look will depend on the projection in use. Here is another view of the same polygon using a mercator projection:

[image: Mercator projection]

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I agree the shape I get is a logical way to join the dots and fill the shape. But the representation I need should still look like a rectangle in equirectangular projection. Understanding that d3 by default will join the dots following the shortest path, led me to find a way to force it to take the longer road. Using projection.clipAngle seems to work.

Comment: @Biovisualize *Ab*using `projection.clipAngle()` feels like cheating to me. I'd consider it a dangerous road because for it to show the desired output it relies on 1) turning off clipping by setting it to >180 degrees, and 2) turning off adaptive resampling by setting `.precision(0)`. Apart from the side-effects of these settings your visualization will break if either of these prerequisites changes.

Comment: I totally agree, but what's the solution to get a rectangle at this position in equirectangular position? Maybe not using d3.geo.path at all?

Comment: @Biovisualize Drawing a line along a parallel will be quite tedious involving lots of intermediate point. I think that would be well worth a new question. It vastly depends on what you are really after. It might even be worth considering using a rectangle which is not projected. But again this depends on what you want to achieve with that rectangle. At the moment your question has some touch of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to explain your actual problem instead of why you think, that your attempted solution has some flaws.

Comment: You're right, I will close this one and your answer makes sense. I need to show it "as a simple rectangle across the map" because it's a bounding box around some features, but the title and the explanation doesn't make it clear. Anyway I have some solutions: the hacky clipping, the simple drawing as a non-projected path (instead of a geo.path, which works in my equirectangular case), and also adding intermediate points for the cutting logic to choose the other way around as the shortest path. Thanks!

Comment: @Biovisualize This still kept me pondering... Finally knowing what your real problem is, I remembered having seen something very similar to this just recently. Have a look at the question [*"D3.geo : Spherical arcs rather than straight lines for parallels?"*](/q/25415885) which should provide exactly the solution you need. Although both answers are really nice, it's the one by Hugolpz which shows how to insert intermediate points to interpolate the parallel's curvature.